# Difference in between ! and !! in angular

Tags: angularjs

What is difference in between !!user.rank and !user.rank

```
<div ng-show="!!user.rank">
    Rank: {{user.rank}}
</div>


<div ng-show="!user.rank">
    <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="KnightMe(user)">Knight       Me</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

! is not operator
!! casts something to truthy / not truthy

```
var foo = 0;
console.log(!!foo);
//false
```

Comment: could you give any reference for !! operator ?

Comment: can we say ! is not operator and !! is for truthy?

Comment: @user3886602 its not an operator its just ! twise ..

Answer (score 1):

`!` converts Object to boolean. If it was falsey (e.g. 0, null, undefined, etc.), it will be false, otherwise, true.

```
!oObject  //Inverted boolean
!!oObject //Non inverted boolean so true boolean representation
```

So !! is not an operator, it's just the ! operator twice

[see the detailed question  and answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)

Comment: @user3886602 mark as answer if this helped :)